# Сброс всех переменных Java

Tags: java, память, gif

Как обнулить все переменные чтобы освободить память? Сборщик мусора не справляется или я глупый. Есть класс (найден на просторах интернета) кодирующий массив картинок в GIF. После использования его методов, память не освобождается. В анализе утечки памяти не разбираюсь. Предполагаю что есть способ как либо "удалить" использованные переменные.
Если у кого нибудь есть опыт кодирования в GIF посоветуйте не тяжелую библиотеку, буду благодарен!

Pastebin с классом: https://pastebin.com/NNheNMw8

[image: Visual VM]:

Comment: > Как обнулить все переменные чтобы освободить память?
Присвоить им значение null и помолиться сборщику мусора ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: В java нет гарантированной возможности вызвать сборщик мусора. Даже если его вызывать, то это будет лишь предложение убраться без всяких гарантий. Сборщик мусора удаляет объекты, недоступные живому потоку. Если вам кажется, что что-то не так, то, может быть, попробовать пересоздать объект этого класса-кодировщика, убедившись, что нигде не сохраняется ссылка на предыдущий объект.

Answer (score 0):

В java нет непосредсвенного способа освободить память. Можно только попытаться уговорить garbage collector очистить объекты, которые он (garbage collector) посчитает нужным удалить.

```
Object obj = new Object();
// use obj
obj = null;
System.gc();
```

И все равно никто не гарантирует, что очистка произойдет